# Stack Status Bar to button application while resize

Tags: wpf, resize, statusbar

So i have `WPF` application:

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="270" />
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
        <RowDefinition Height="260" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

In the last `Row` i have `StatusBar`:

```
<Grid Name="gridStatusBar" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,0,0">
  <StatusBar>
      <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Left">
           <Label
                FontSize="13"
                FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"
                Foreground="Gainsboro"
                Margin="0,-3,0,0"/>
      </StatusBarItem>
  </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

So in case of resize my application i cannot see my `StatusBar`, i try to add `VerticalAlignment="Bottom"` and `VerticalAlignment="Top"` but this still
not helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Grid` effectively has a fixed height of 270 + 200 + 260 + 30 = 760.

You should use relative (star *) sizes if you want it to be able to shrink and grow dynamically:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="270*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="200*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="260*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="30" /> <!-- only this height is actually fixed -->
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Another option would be to use another kind of `Panel`, such as for example a `DockPanel` and always dock the `StatusBar` to the bottom:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid Name="gridStatusBar" Height="30" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <StatusBar>
            <StatusBarItem HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Label
                FontSize="13"
                FontFamily="Comic Sans MS"
                Foreground="Gainsboro"
                Margin="0,-3,0,0"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="270" />
            <RowDefinition Height="200" />
            <RowDefinition Height="260" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: In your example the DockPanel should envelop the main grid also ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't assuming you always want the StatusBar at the bottom.

Comment: Try it out for yourself.